# Cannot pass model between view and action method in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have action methods and views that are used to authenticate to a domain. The COM object is then passed to the view bellow. If a user clicks a button I want to do something (as seen in the action method below) for which I need the COM object. The problem is that the the model Connector is passed as null.

**View:**

```
@model Decsec.Models.Connector

@using (Html.BeginForm("ClassifyPrivUsers", "AuthenticateAD", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <input type="submit" value="Evaluate" class="btn btn btn-block" name="ClassifyPrivUsers" formmethod="post" />
        }
```

**Action Method:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ClassifyPrivUsers(Connector connector)
    {
        // Extract privileged users from the Active Directory
        var privilegedUsers = ADExtractor.PrivilegedAccess(connector.pc);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PRIVILEGED USERS EXTRACTED");

        // Load the trained model for privileged users
        Classifier adminAccCl = LoadModel("LMT");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MODEL LOADED");
.....
```

**Model:**

```
public class Connector
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public PrincipalContext pc { get; set; }
    public DirectoryEntry de { get; set; }

    public Connector(int id, PrincipalContext pc, DirectoryEntry de)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.pc = pc;
        this.de = de;
    }

    public Connector() { }
}
```

Comment: Your form does not include any inputs for properties of `Connector` But what are your trying to do here - what would be the point of sending a model to the client and then sending it back again unchanged?

Comment: @StephenMuecke The idea is that I want to keep the COM object alive so that I can use it in the action above. I have tried `@using (Html.BeginForm("ClassifyPrivUsers", "AuthenticateAD", FormMethod.Post, Model.pc))` but it does not send the model back to the action.

Comment: Use hidden fields for each model property.

Comment: The 4th parameter of your `BeginForm()`in your last comment adds html attributes, not route parameters.

Comment: @StephenMuecke How should I pass the model then?

Comment: You should not (its crazy to send something to the client that is not used and then send to all back again unchanged). But since `Connector` contains properties which are complex objects, you cannot use one of the overloads of `BeginForm`. You would need to create hidden inputs for each property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke How do I create hidden inputs for the particular case? I cannot seems to find a good explanation.

Comment: Look up @Html.HiddenFor()

Comment: If your `pc` property is this [PrincipalContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) you cant anyway - it does not have a parameterless constructor. But as I noted, it would be crazy to do so anyway